# Python string split using regex

Tags: python, regex

I need to parse a line like these:

```
foo, bar > 1.0, baz = 2.0
foo  bar > 1.0  baz = 2.0
foo, bar, baz
foo  bar  baz
```

for each element it can be $string (>|<|<=|>=|=) $num or just $string, separator ',' is optional between the elements.

in all these cases, recognize them as:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

how could I do this in python?

Comment: What happens if there is only `foo, bar` or `bar > 1.0  baz = 2.0` in a line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one checks for the syntax also:

```
import re
with open("input") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        # chop a line into expressions of the form: str [OP NUMBER]
        exprs = re.split(r'(\w+\s*(?:[!<>=]=?\s*[\d.]*)?\s*,?\s*)', line)
        for expr in exprs:
            # chop each expression into tokens and get the str part
            tokens = re.findall(r'(\w+)\s*(?:[!<>=]=?\s*[\d.]*)?,?', expr)
            if tokens: print tokens
```

Comment: This is very close to what I want, my question is not well described,    it should be str [OP str], and str can contains number too, I'm trying to figure out a solution based on your answer, thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

You can split at every non alphabetic characters

```
re.split("[^a-zA-Z]+",input)
```

Though am assuming that your `$string` contain only alphabets..

---

You can remove empty results with [filter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)

```
filter(None, str_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just extract all the letter groups:

```
s = """
foo, bar > 1.0, baz = 2.0
foo  bar > 1.0  baz = 2.0
foo, bar, baz
foo  bar  baz
"""

import re
regex = re.compile(r'([a-z]+)', re.I)  # re.I (ignore case flag)

for line in s.splitlines():
    if not line:
        continue # skip empty lines

    print regex.findall(line)

>>> 
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Comment: should probably be `[a-zA-Z]+` to include capitals as well, no?

Comment: Or use the ignorecase flag.